# apache permission problems

Tags: centos, apache-httpd

I have some question about permission for my apache.

The following situation came in a test up:
I want to install wordpress and the setup told me that he can not create the file `wp-config.php`. 
So I noticed that there is a permission problem. But how can I fix this?

All folders in var/www/html are owned by apache:apache and has 755 permissions (drwxr-xr-x).

What information you need to give me some suggestions?

Comment: I think apache runs as httpd user on centos, no ?

Comment: I dunno know really. I installed apache with sudo yum -y apache

Comment: what is the ouput of `lsof -i TCP:80` [edit] your question so everybody knows also you should add the installation method to your question it could help Also did you created tha apache user ? if you did how did you ?

Comment: lsof command not found

Answer (score 0):

You should allow the user on which privileges apache process is running to write to this file. 
To check the name of user used by apache process you can run `ps -ef | grep httpd` and then set the owner for `wp-config.php` file but after installation will be finished you should disallow apache to make changes on this file.

Comment: Thanks, but I need a solution that this will work for new folders and domains. I changed the owner to apache:apache for var/www/html/ and 755. But it is also not working.

Comment: You changed permission for /var/www/html directory but what with files and sub-directories inside?

Comment: Also changed to this.

Comment: OK, you use mod_php with apache or php-fpm?

Comment: I use CGI for PHP

Comment: Could you please update wp-content folder permission to 777 then try to install wordpress.

Comment: Makes no difference. Wordpress can not create wp-config.php

Comment: Maybe I have the problem. I temporarily disabled SELinux now it works. What kind of permission I have to set on SELinux to get the think working with SELinux active?

Comment: About fix SELinux permission for apache you can read here: https://blog.lysender.com/2015/07/centos-7-selinux-php-apache-cannot-writeaccess-file-no-matter-what/

Answer (score 0):

we need to temporarily grant `httpd_sys_rw_content_t` to the WordPress directory. This is to allow the initial wizard to create the `wp-config.php` file.

```
sudo chcon -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /var/www/html/wordpress/
```

Now you can run the wizard and it will work properly.

Once your site is set up, restore the context to http_sys_content_t

```
sudo restorecon -v /var/www/html/wordpress/
```

Comment: Is there a way to enable this always?

Comment: then don't restore the context.